# WP-Cron system broken

Tags: wp-cron

None of my cron events fire. I have deactivated all plugins on the site, and I made sure that I have not disabled wp-cron in the config file. I use AWS for hosting.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I have re-enabled one plugin to test cron issues - WP-Cron Events

The plugin generates a table populated with all cron events. Also, there is a error message that is generated that you can see in the screenshot I have attached.

[image: Cron Events]

Comment: A simple google says a http 401 code is "unauthorized access"

Comment: Yes, I was aware of what the 401 meant. If you can, can you elaborate on why this message would be appearing? I'm not sure why it would be appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I was running into the issue of the same message within WP-Cron Events but instead with a 404 "not found" code...it's hunting for the file http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php.  My issue turned out to be an improper file permission on my wp-cron.php file (644 instead of 666) which caused the wp-cron.php file to give the 404...  Fixed the permissions and now the warning is gone.  This file gives a 200 code now, and cron jobs finally started to run again.

Maybe the 401 that you are receiving is caused by permissions issues on this file as well?

Comment: Well, that was it. Thank you for the reply, it was worth a lot. Glad to have my cron jobs firing. I have no idea how this could have happened to begin with though.